# Is it possible to convert Realm Object to JSON Object?

Tags: android, json, realm

I have a problem with sending a list of objects from my Realm database to a web server. The app should save the transaction locally(I used realm database) when there is no internet connection detected. Then, when the app detects the internet connection, the data from my realm database should be sent to a web server using JSON format.
Tia.

Comment: Realm object is java object, soo yes, it is possible..

Comment: i tried Realm with GSON, but i can't make the Realm object to a POJO.

Comment: Use `gson.toJson(realm.copyFromRealm(myObj))`. That should work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you have to register `TypeAdapter` for your class and define an exclusion strategy for your classes extends `RealmObject`.

For example you have an `User` class like the following:

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    // Getter and setter methods.
}
```

You have to create a User `Serializer`:

```
public class UserSerializer implements JsonSerializer<User> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(User user, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("id", user.getId());
        jsonObject.addProperty("email", user.getEmail());
        jsonObject.addProperty("name", user.getName());
    }
}
```

Finally you have to register this as a `TypeAdapter` to your Gson and add an exclusion strategy for `Realm`.

```
  new GsonBuilder()
        .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserSerializer())
        .create();
```

I think this'll help you. Good luck.

Comment: You don't need the custom type adapter anymore. Just send a detached copy to GSON instead using `realm.copyFromRealm(obj)`.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I want to parse JSON based data to my object which extends Realm. can you help on it? I don't want to store the data, I just want to parse.